# How can I extract all content from all elements of an XML file with Python and ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following XML file called Artists.xml, which contains information on several artists as shown bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Artists>
<Singer name="Britney">
    <Albums>7</Albums>
    <Country>USA</County>
    <Last Single>  Piece of Me
      <Year>2011</Year>
   </Last Single>
</Singer>
<Singer name="Justin">
    <Albums>8</Albums>
    <Country>USA</County>
    <Last Single> Rock Your Body
      <Year>2004</Year>
   </Last Single>
</Singer>
</Artsts>
```

I am using the Python library ElementTree in order to extract the content of all tags. So far this is the Python code I have written:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('Artists.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    for content in child:
       print(child[content].text)
```

Despite that, when I run the script I see no inputs in my console. I would like to see something like : `7  USA   Piece of Me  2011, 8  USA  Rock Your Body  2004.` Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your xml is not properly formatted.

Comment: User [ElementTree.iterparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse)

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach. Convert the XML to dict and print the dict. (The file 55726013.xml contains your sample data). As you can see the code has zero knowledge about the XML structure.

```
import xmltodict
import json

with open('55726013.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

print(json.dumps(doc, indent=4))
```

Output

```
{
    "Artists": {
        "Singer": [
            {
                "@name": "Britney", 
                "Albums": "7", 
                "Country": "USA", 
                "LastSingle": {
                    "Year": "2011", 
                    "#text": "Piece of Me"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "@name": "Justin", 
                "Albums": "8", 
                "Country": "USA", 
                "LastSingle": {
                    "Year": "2004", 
                    "#text": "Rock Your Body"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Artists>
    <Singer name="Britney">
        <Albums>7</Albums>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <LastSingle>
               Piece of Me
              <Year>2011</Year>
       </LastSingle>
    </Singer>
    <Singer name="Justin">
        <Albums>8</Albums>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <LastSingle> Rock Your Body
          <Year>2004</Year>
       </LastSingle>
    </Singer>
</Artists>
```

**Hence**:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
results = root.findall('Singer')

for elem in results:
    for e in elem:
        print(e.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
7
USA
Piece of Me
8
USA
Rock Your Body

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!  What if I have a large document and I still want every content to be printed but dont know what child node are contained in the tree root?